# xsl substring-after usage

Tags: xslt

I have this XSL code and I would like to configure the string. However I couldn't get the configured string yet. What could be the matter?

```
<xsl:param name="topicId"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="topicName"/>

 <xsl:attribute-set name="attrTopic">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
  <xsl:value-of select="/message/file/@name[substring-after($topicId,'-')]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="/message/file/@name[substring-before(' ',$topicId)]"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
<xsl:attribute-set name="attrVars">
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

$topicId comes from my Java file. in sum I am trying to convert this string "1010-Text" to "1010" and "Text" separately in XSL

Comment: Can you provide a sample output and input? Are you trying to get the attribute `id="text"` etc in the output? etc. or are you trying to match the value of @name to 'text'? Or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the *context* is correct and `$topicId='WordA-WordB'`

```
substring-after($topicId,'-')
```

should get `WordB` and

```
substring-before(' ',$topicId)
```

should get nothing.

While

```
substring-before($topicId,'-')
```

shoud get `WordA`.