# XPATH Search and replace full words

Tags: xpath

Strange I can't find this information online, does anyone know how to search and replace a full word for something else?

For example:

```
<div class="cell_user" alt="hotel Review - Young couple">
```

I want to remove: "hotel Review - " so I am left with:

"Young couple"

It seems to be something to do with fn:replace but I cannot find a single example anywhere of someone using it!

Thanks for any advice

Comment: XPath can only query XML documents, not modify them. You will need XQuery or XSLT for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a constant prefix or infix string as in your example you can always use a string function such as `substring-after()`:

```
"substring-after(//div[@class = 'cell_user']/@alt, 'hotel Review - ')"
```

You may want to tweak the beginning of the XPath expression a little bit to be more selective depending on your context. Also see [xsl substring-after usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293945/xsl-substring-after-usage).

If you know that the relevant part is always after a hyphen and there is always only a single hyphen in your string you may even write

```
"substring-after(//div[@class = 'cell_user']/@alt, '- ')"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your responses. Just to clarify, I went with this in the end: `code`normalize-space(substring-after(.//div[@class='cell_user']/@alt, '-'))`code` I see how you have left the space after the dash , maybe I'll adapt and do the same @Marcus.